# Ninject - do scopes apply to a binding or the target object?

Tags: ninject

Will the following code in Ninject use the same instance of UnitOfWork for both bindings, or will two total instances per request be created, one for each binding?

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
Bind<UnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
```

If the former is not the case, how can I make requests for IUnitOfWork and UnitOfWork both activate the same UnitOfWork instance for the same request?

I have a module where one of the internal classes depends on a property in the specific implementation of IUnitOfWork which is why I need the self-binding as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ninject 3.0.0 allows you to

```
Bind<UnitOfWork, IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
```

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question no, these will create different instances depending on wheather you request IUnitOfWork or UnitOfWork. To get around this add the ContextPreservation extension and use the following binding:

```
Bind<UnitOfWork>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
this.BindInterfaceToBinding<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

Heres Remos post on why you do this and some other alternatives if you dont want to import the library http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/12/08/ninject-extension-contextpreservation-explained/